# VS Code: main branch not updating. Also switching to main branch from experimental branch keeps changes from experimental

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

`[o]` for original

`[f]` for forked (off of original)

`[l]` for local

my branches:

- main `[lf]`
- branch1 `[lf]`
- branch2 `[lf]`
- main `[o]`

Need some help syncing my `main` branch in a forked repo `[f]` with the original repo's main branch (`upstream/main` `[o]`). I want the two branches (`[f]` `main` and `[o]` `main`) to be the same but my local branch `main` `[f]` is not updating with the original repo's branch `upstream/main` `[o]`.

When I use git fetch upstream or git pull, the main branch `[l]` I'm on does not update with the original repo `[o]`. It stays the same. When I run `git remote -v`, things look as they should. But when I run git `fetch origin`, `git fetch upstream`, `git fetch upstream/main`, or `git pull`, I don't get the update I want. When I run `git fetch upstream --verbose`, I get this:

fetch upstream --verbose

```
 From github.com:repoUrlOriginalRepo/repo
  = [up to date]      master     -> upstream/main
  = [up to date]      main       -> upstream/main
```

git fetch origin --verbose

```
From github.com:user/repo
 = [up to date]      main       -> origin/main
 = [up to date]      user/branch1 -> origin/user/branch1
 = [up to date]      user/branch2 -> origin/user/branch2
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
```

git pull --verbose

```
From github.com:repoUrlOriginalRepo/repo
 = [up to date]      main       -> origin/main
 = [up to date]      user/branch1 -> origin/user/branch1
 = [up to date]      user/branch2 -> origin/user/branch2
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
Already up to date.
```

Something weird is going on because in addition to not being able to pull changes from the original [o], when I make changes in my experimental branch [l] (for example `branch1`) and then switch to my `main` branch [l], it keeps the changes from the other branch (`branch1`) instead of removing the changes which should only exist in my experimental branch (`branch1`).

Thanks so much for the help :)

PS: I guess I should also mention that I have no master branch. I wanted `main` to be my master branch. running `git checkout master` gives the error: `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: Can you clarify: your local branch name, your desired local branch name, and which remote is the fork and which is yours?

Comment: You likely want to do git checkout REPO BRANCH or git pull REPO BRANCH. Where REPO and BRANCH are the original repo and the branch you want to sync with.

Comment: Added some details to clarify the branches I am talking about. Also, when I checkout my `upstream/main` branch (the original branch) that is the one I want, then I get a 'detached HEAD' state. What does this mean? When I go to my `main` branch and run `git pull upstream/main`, I get this: `atal: 'upstream/next' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` Why is it saying this?

Comment: You have a lot of questions here (SO is meant for 1 at a time) - I'd suggest taking the time to read up/google them individually. I suggested `git pull upstream main` - notice how it uses a space instead of `/`